# Getting error while fetching chromium source code

Tags: web-applications, desktop-application, chromium, webviewchromium

I followed the instructions given on the link https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md

and tried with different fetch commands such as --no-history,nohooks,etc.
But it keeps on failing with the following error:

```
C:\chromium_nohistory>fetch --no-history chromium
Running: 'C:\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe' 'C:\depot_tools\gclient.py' root
Running: 'C:\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe' 'C:\depot_tools\gclient.py' config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git",
    "managed": False,
    "name": "src",
    "deps_file": ".DEPS.git",
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
'
Running: 'C:\depot_tools\python276_bin\python.exe' 'C:\depot_tools\gclient.py' sync --no-history
Error: Command 'C:\\depot_tools\\python276_bin\\python.exe src/build/landmines.py' returned non-zero exit status 1 in C:\chromium_nohistory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 300, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 295, in main
    return run(options, spec, root)
  File "C:\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 289, in run
    return checkout.init()
  File "C:\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 132, in init
    self.run_gclient(*sync_cmd)
  File "C:\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 76, in run_gclient
    return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, kwargs)
  File "C:\depot_tools\\fetch.py", line 66, in run
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd, kwargs)
  File "C:\depot_tools\python276_bin\lib\subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('C:\\depot_tools\\python276_bin\\python.exe', 'C:\\depot_tools\\gclient.py', 'sync', '--no-history')' **returned non-zero exit status 2**
```

I am new to the chromium so is there anything that i am missing,
Any help in this appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Create DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN system variable, and set it to 0**

This setting I missed that's why the error came.
After doing this everything worked very smooth.